# Is it possible to select button with only class values in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium

Is it possible to select button with only class values in Selenium Python?
The html is as follows:

```
<button class="secondary option-action ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"


from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(any_url)
```

Any idea to select that button?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Use [`find_element_by_class_name`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_class_name) (or `find_elements_by_class_name` to get multiple matched elements):

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name('secondary')
```

You can also use [`find_element_by_css_selector`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_css_selector) (or ..s variant):

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.secondary')
```

Alternatively you can also use `find_element_by_xpath`, but it requires a verbose xpath expression to be precise:

```
xpath = "descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' secondary ')]"
browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use css selctors:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".secondary")
```

multiple classes:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".secondary.option-action.ui-button.ui-widget")
```

you can also use:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[role=button]")
```

in case theres multiple buttons with the same classes you can do this:

```
<div id="button-is-here">
<button class="secondary option-action ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
</div>

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#button-is-here .secondary.option-action.ui-button.ui-widget")
```

If you only use classes most likely there will be another button in the page with the same classes so sometimes you have to be more specific

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you a similar answer to the one I gave you on your previous question:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="secondary option-action..."]').click()
```

You'll have to fill the `...` yourself though, or instead, use:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[starts-with(@class,"secondary option")]').click()
```

If you don't have any other `input` element whose `class` attribute starts with "secondary option"...